# java Условие прохождения 24 часов

Tags: java, android, дата

Здравствуйте, есть следующая задачка, оповестить пользователя о прохождения 24 часов с момента нажатия на кнопку. Текущее время получаю:

```
SessdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
SessdateFormat.format( new Date())
```

Какое условие создать оповещения Toast, что прошло 24 часа с текущего момента?

Comment: `AlarmManager`, только чтобы `DozeMode` не прибил его

Comment: можно с сервера пушем оповещать

Comment: как это реализовать(пример)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В момент создания уведомления, можно создать поток, который выполнит задачу через указанное время.

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = 
                                      Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

executorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
            System.out.println("wake up!");
            //завершаем поток
            executorService.shutdown();
        }
}, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```